# Class Based Generic UpdateView inline

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have the following models

```
class Cv(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=250)
    objective = models.CharField(_('objective'), max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)

class Position(models.Model):
    cv = models.ForeignKey(Cv, verbose_name=_('cv'))
    start = models.DateField(_('start'))
    end = models.DateField(_('end'))
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=250)
    currently_employed = models.BooleanField(_('currently employed'))
    sector = models.IntegerField(_('sector'), choices=SECTOR_CHOICES)
    duties = models.TextField(_('duties'))
```

and the following forms:

```
class CvForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cv

class PositionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Position
        widgets = {
            'start': DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
            'end': DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
        }

PositionFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Cv, Position, form=PositionForm, extra=1)
```

I have created the following Generic CreateView which works great:

```
class CreateCvView(CreateView):
    model = Cv
    form_class = CvForm
    template_name = 'recruitment/cv/cv_detail.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        self.success_url = '/'
        return self.success_url

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateCvView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['position_form'] = PositionFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['position_form'] = PositionFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.slug = slugify(self.request.user)
        context = self.get_context_data()
        position_form = context['position_form']
        if position_form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            position_form.instance = self.object
            position_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

What I want to do is an UpdateView and so I copied the createview and passed it the slug as follows:

```
class EditCvView(UpdateView):
    model = Cv
    form_class = CvForm
    template_name = 'recruitment/cv/cv_detail.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        self.success_url = '/'
        return self.success_url

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EditCvView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['position_form'] = PositionFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['position_form'] = PositionFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.slug = slugify(self.request.user)
        context = self.get_context_data()
        position_form = context['position_form']
        if position_form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            position_form.instance = self.object
            position_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

It loads fine but when I post the form I get a 'list index out of range' error on PositionFormSet(self.request.POST) in get_context_data. Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Thanks!! Nevermind I found this https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views which pretty much does everything so I'm using the inline create and update views from this.

Answer (score 0):

in EditCvView:

context['position_form'] = PositionFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)

Comment: I am giving up on formsets, I create mine like this and want only 5 items: PurchaserChoiceFormset = inlineformset_factory(Worksheet, PurchaserChoice, form=PurchaserChoiceForm, can_delete=False,
                                               extra=5, max_num=5)  Once the 5th item is created and the form is re-saved it creates a new extra Purchase Choice Item! My code for saving is:         if context['choice_formset'].is_valid():
            context['choice_formset'].instance = context['worksheet']
            context['choice_formset'].save()