# Django class-based CreateView and UpdateView with multiple inline formsets

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have been trying to do Django class-based CreateView and UpdateView with multiple inline formsets

CreateView works fine but UpdateView is not working properly, If anyone tried UpdateView with multiple inline formsets, anyone tried pls share updateview code snippet.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Instruction(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()


# forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from .models import Recipe, Ingredient, Instruction

class RecipeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe

IngredientFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Recipe, Ingredient, extra=0)
InstructionFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Recipe, Instruction, extra=0)


# views.py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from .forms import IngredientFormSet, InstructionFormSet, RecipeForm
from .models import Recipe

class RecipeCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'recipe_add.html'
    model = Recipe
    form_class = RecipeForm
    success_url = '/account/dashboard/'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        ingredient_form = IngredientFormSet()
        instruction_form = InstructionFormSet()
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  ingredient_form=ingredient_form,
                                  instruction_form=instruction_form))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        ingredient_form = IngredientFormSet(self.request.POST)
        instruction_form = InstructionFormSet(self.request.POST)
        if (form.is_valid() and ingredient_form.is_valid() and
            instruction_form.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form, ingredient_form, instruction_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, ingredient_form, instruction_form)

    def form_valid(self, form, ingredient_form, instruction_form):
        self.object = form.save()
        ingredient_form.instance = self.object
        ingredient_form.save()
        instruction_form.instance = self.object
        instruction_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form, ingredient_form, instruction_form):
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  ingredient_form=ingredient_form,
                                  instruction_form=instruction_form))

class RecipeUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'recipe_add.html'
    model = Recipe
    form_class = RecipeForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        self.success_url = '/account/dashboard/'
        return self.success_url

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RecipeUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['form'] = RecipeForm(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
            context['ingredient_form'] = IngredientFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
            context['instruction_form'] = InstructionFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            context['form'] = RecipeForm(instance=self.object)
            context['ingredient_form'] = IngredientFormSet(instance=self.object)
            context['instruction_form'] = InstructionFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        ingredient_form = IngredientFormSet(self.request.POST)
        instruction_form = InstructionFormSet(self.request.POST)
        if (form.is_valid() and ingredient_form.is_valid() and
            instruction_form.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form, ingredient_form, instruction_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, ingredient_form, instruction_form)

    def form_valid(self, form, ingredient_form, instruction_form):
        self.object = form.save()
        ingredient_form.instance = self.object
        ingredient_form.save()
        instruction_form.instance = self.object
        instruction_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form, ingredient_form, instruction_form):
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  ingredient_form=ingredient_form,
                                  instruction_form=instruction_form))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Original post [Django class-based views with multiple inline formsets](http://kevindias.com/writing/django-class-based-views-multiple-inline-formsets/)

Comment: @vishes_shell that link is dead now.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that the regular form of the updateview has to be added to the context because it is there anyways. A working Updateview with inlineformsets could be achieved less complicated. I based this on this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070518/class-based-generic-updateview-inline)

```
class RecipeUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Recipe
    form_class = RecipeUpdateForm
    success_url = "/foo/"

    def get_success_url(self):
        self.success_url = '/account/dashboard/'
        return self.success_url

    def get_object(self):
        return #your object

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RecipeUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['ingredient_form'] = IngredientFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
            context['instruction_form'] = InstructionFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            context['ingredient_form'] = IngredientFormSet(instance=self.object)
            context['instruction_form'] = InstructionFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        ingredient_form = context['ingredient_form']
        instruction_form = context['instruction_form']
        if ingredient_form.is_valid() and instruction_form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            ingredient_form.instance = self.object
            ingredient_form.save()
            instruction_form.instance = self.object
            instruction_form.save()
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Answer (score 7):

My guess is that you can't do

```
self.object = None
```

on overwritten `post` method in a `UpdateView`. So, try

```
self.object = self.get_object()
```

instead, once you already have an object instance in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you've found an answer, but I have a working version of UpdateView documented in my answer found here:

[UpdateView with inline formsets trying to save duplicate records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575535/django-updateview-with-inline-formsets-trying-to-save-duplicate-records)

Comment: This link provides the way. Pay attention to the use of `instance`, as opposed to `initial`, in the get function's formset definition, and `self.object = self.get_object` instead of `None`

Answer (score 0):

So I recognize the models form this [post](http://kevindias.com/writing/django-class-based-views-multiple-inline-formsets/). To get UpdateView working properly you are going to have to do at least two, maybe three things:

1. Update the `self.object = self.get_object()` -- after that, your ability to dynamically add should work.
2. To get the dynamic deletes updating properly, you will need to alter the template with form.DELETE (in two places, the ingredients and the instructions).

   ```
   {{ form.description }}
   {% if form.instance.pk %}{{ form.DELETE }}{% endif %}
   ```
3. Not sure it was necessary but I added can_delete to the factory too.

   ```
   IngredientFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Recipe, Ingredient, fields=('description',), extra=3, can_delete=True)
   InstructionFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Recipe, Instruction, fields=('number', 'description',), extra=1, can_delete=True)
   ```

Comment: The link in this comment is dead.