# Django - UpdateView with inline formsets trying to save duplicate records?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have an `Expense` model and an `ExpenseLineItem` model. Just like a typical expense/invoice, one expense can have several line items to make up the total cost of an invoice. I'm trying to use class based views to create and update expenses. I've successfully coded the `CreateView` to make a new expense with multiple expense line items.

My problem is when I try and update an existing Expense which already has several expense line items. Here's my code below, and I can't figure out what the issue is. The mixins (`TitleMixin`, `CancelSuccessMixin`, `SelectedApartment`)are mine and work fine.

I'm getting an error that, I believe, means that it's trying to save a *new* copy of the `ExpenseLineItems` but fails since those already exist. Almost like I'm not providing an `instance` argument.

What am I doing wrong?

**forms.py**

```
class ExpenseForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Expense
    fields = ['apart', 'inv_num', 'vendor', 'due_date']

ExpenseLineItemFormset = inlineformset_factory(Expense, ExpenseLineItem, fields=('description', 'account', 'amt'), can_delete=False)
```

Here's my `ExpenseUpdate` view:

```
class ExpenseUpdate(TitleMixin, CancelSuccessMixin, SelectedApartment, UpdateView):
  model = Expense
  form_class = ExpenseForm
  template_name = 'accounting/expense.html'

  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    expense_line_item_form = ExpenseLineItemFormset(instance = self.object)
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form = form, expense_line_item_form = expense_line_item_form))

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    expense_line_item_form = ExpenseLineItemFormset(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)

    if (form.is_valid() and expense_line_item_form.is_valid()):
      return self.form_valid(form, expense_line_item_form)
    return self.form_invalid(form, expense_line_item_form)

  def form_valid(self, form, expense_line_item_form):
    self.object = form.save()
    expense_line_item_form.instance = self.object
    expense_line_item_form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

  def form_invalid(self, form, expense_line_item_form):
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, expense_line_item_form=expense_line_item_form))
```

Error code I get:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /stuff/2/accounting/update-expense/25/
"u'expenselineitem_set-0-id'"
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/stuff/2/accounting/update-expense/25/
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
"u'expenselineitem_set-0-id'"
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 322
```

**Edit**: Relevant part of my template:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% load widget_tweaks %}
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-tight">
        <thead>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th class="text-right">Account</th>
          <th class="text-right">Amount</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {{ expense_line_item_form.management_form }}
          {% for eli in expense_line_item_form %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ eli.description|attr:'cols:29' }}</td>
            <td class="text-right">{{ eli.account }}</td>
            <td class="text-right">{{ eli.amt }}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
    <a href="{{ cancel }}" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Cancel</a>
    <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit" value="Post" />
  </div>
  <br><br>
</form>
```

**EDIT -- Working Form Template** I thought I would add the working version of my template, should someone else need it:

```
    <tbody>
      {{ expense_line_item_form.management_form }}
      {% for eli in expense_line_item_form %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ eli.id }} {{ eli.description|attr:'cols:29' }}</td> <!-- <<==== Here's where I simply added {{ eli.id }}. That's all I changed :) -->
        <td class="text-right">{{ eli.account }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ eli.amt }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Please show your template. Make sure you are including `{{ form.id }}` for each form in the formset.

Comment: @Alasdair I've added my template. But I'm not sure that including `{{ form.id }}` is necessary based on how formsets work. I've used formsets in the past, and haven't needed to include the PK when updating an existing set of records. But certainly I may be wrong here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do need form id. See my answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to include the form id for each form in the formset (it won't be shown to the user, as it is rendered as a hidden input). Without that form, the value is missing from the POST data, and you get a `KeyError` as you are seeing.

From the [formset docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template):

> Notice how we need to explicitly render `{{ form.id }}`. This ensures that the model formset, in the POST case, will work correctly. (This example assumes a primary key named id. If you’ve explicitly defined your own primary key that isn’t called id, make sure it gets rendered.)

In your case, you are looping through the formset with `{% for eli in expense_line_item_form %}`, so you need to include `{{ eli.id }}`.

Comment: Awesome, you are correct! Thanks for this :) In the past when using formsets, I hadn't needed the `{{ form.id }}` field, but perhaps this was due to it being an older version of DJango.

Comment: I don't think the `{{ form.id}}` is a new requirement, so I don't know why it might have worked without it in the past. The formset internals are pretty complex, so I avoid looking in there when I can!

Comment: These answers helped me identify that when using [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form_helper.html), you must set `FormHelper.render_required_fields = True` in order to include the `id` field in an formset.

Comment: The {{form.id}} thing is because if you iterate with something like {% for field in form %}, then Django will automatically include it for you (since it's one of the fields in the form). However, if you manually render each field, you have to do it yourself.