# CreateView with inline form with boolean only fields failing to create

Tags: django, django-1.8, inline-formset

Ok so I have a a generic CreateView with a couple of inlineformset_factory additions. Similar to the examples here:
[Django class-based CreateView and UpdateView with multiple inline formsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876644/django-class-based-createview-and-updateview-with-multiple-inline-formsets)

One is generating a new record on save with the parent model as expected, however a second which only contains boolean fields is not. I am not generating my own model form for either inline formset but using the default. As soon as i add a charfield field to the offending model the save works and i can see the new record, with only booleans fields in that inline formset (and model) i get nothing no record and no errors.

Edit code samples>

```
#models.py
class Mentor(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=SALUTATION_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=80)
    last_name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=80)

class MentorSetting(models.Model):
    mentor = models.OneToOneField('Mentor')
    mentor_status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    question_status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

#forms.py
class MentorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mentor
        fields = ['title','first_name','last_name',]

SettingsFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Mentor, MentorSetting,
        fields=('mentor_status','question_status',),
        extra=1,
        can_delete=True)

#views.py
class MentorCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'mentor/mentor_form.html'
    model = Mentor
    form_class = MentorForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        settings_form = SettingsFormSet()
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,                                 
                                  settings_form=settings_form))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        settings_form = SettingsFormSet(self.request.POST)
        if (form.is_valid() and settings_form.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form, settings_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, settings_form)

    def form_valid(self, form, settings_form):
        self.object = form.save()
        settings_form.instance = self.object
        settings_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_valid(self, form, settings_form):
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  settings_form=settings_form))
```

If anyone can explain why would be awesome.

mathew

Comment: You'd really need to provide code examples for us to answer.

Comment: Added some code above. have taken out the other working formset for simplicity

Comment: There are two form_valid methods there, is that a typo/cut 'n paste error?