# Using formsets to upload many files to a record, it isn't quite working

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset, inline-formset

I have used as many examples online as I could cobble together in an attempt to get my two simple models:

```
class Technical_Entry(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ema = models.ForeignKey(EMA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    system = models.ForeignKey('System', on_delete=models.CASCADE) # are SYSTEMS RELATED TO SUBSYSTEMS OR JUST TWO GROUPS?  
    sub_system = models.ForeignKey(SubSystem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    drawing_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    drawing_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    engineer = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    date_drawn = models.DateField()
    ab = models.BooleanField()



class Technical_Entry_Files(models.Model):
    tech_entry = models.ForeignKey(Technical_Entry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='techdb/files/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tech_entry.drawing_number
```

To upload using a formset.  While the page 'displays' mostly correctly, it flat out does not create the record in the Technical_Entry_Files model.

Relevant forms.py:

```
class FileUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FileUploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()  
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
    
    class Meta:
        model = Technical_Entry_Files
        fields = ('file',)


TechFileFormSet  = inlineformset_factory(Technical_Entry, Technical_Entry_Files, form=FileUploadForm, extra=1)



class Technical_EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Technical_EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()  
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))

    class Meta:
        model = Technical_Entry
        fields = ('category', 'ema', 'system', 'sub_system', 'drawing_number', 'drawing_title', 'engineer', 'vendor', 'date_drawn', 'ab')


        widgets = {
            'date_drawn':DateInput(attrs={
            'class':'datepicker form-control',        
            'id' : 'datetimepicker2',
            'tabindex' : '1',
            'placeholder' : 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm',          
            'autocomplete':'off',
            }, format='%m/%d/%Y'),

            'system' : Select(attrs={'tabindex':'2'}),
        }
```

Relevant views.py:

```
class TechEntryUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):                                                                                             

    model = Technical_Entry
    form_class = Technical_EntryForm
    template_name = 'techdb/tech_entry_form.html'
    success_url = '/'
                                                                                             
    log_entry_class = Technical_EntryForm(Technical_Entry)
                                                                                         

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TechEntryUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.request.POST:
            context["file_upload"] = TechFileFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES,instance=self.object)
        else:
            context["file_upload"] = TechFileFormSet(instance=self.object)

#        entry = context['object'] 
 #       context['entry_id'] = entry.id
  #      theEntry = Technical_Entry.objects.get(pk=entry.id) 
#        entry_form = Technical_EntryForm(instance=theEntry)
#        context['entry_form'] = entry_form         
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        file_upload = context["file_upload"]
        self.object = form.save()
        if file_upload.is_valid():
            file_upload.instance =self.object
            file_upload.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

class TechEntryCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    print ("we are here")
    model = Technical_Entry
    form_class = Technical_EntryForm
    template_name = 'techdb/tech_entry_form.html'
    print(template_name)
    success_url = '/techentry_add'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(TechEntryCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['file_upload'] = TechFileFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        else:
            data['file_upload'] = TechFileFormSet()
        return data


    def form_valid(self, form):
        context =self.get_context_data()
        file_upload = context['file_upload']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if file_upload.is_valid():
                file_upload.instance =self.object
                file_upload.save()
        return super(TechEntryCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

and the tech_entry_form.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% load static %}

{% block page-js %}

<script>
    $('.link-formset').formset({
        addText: 'add file',
        deleteText: 'remove',        
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<main role="main" class="container">

      <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>New Tech Entry</h1>
      </div>

    <h2> Details of Technical Entry </h2>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
       <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}

                <h2> Files </h2>
                {{ file_upload.management_form }}
                {% for upload_form in file_upload.forms %}
                  <div class="link-formset">
                    {{ upload_form.file }}        
                  </div>
                 {% endfor %}

               
                <input type="submit" value="Save"/><a href="{% url 'tech_database:index' %}">back to the list</a>
            </form>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </main><!-- /.container -->


{% endblock %}
```

It will save the entry but not the file that was uploaded, and I see no errors either.

There is no techdb/files folder (maybe I have to create that?) but it certainly does not fail anywhere...creates the Technical_Entry record, but not the Technical_Entry_Files record nor is there any thing on disk added.

Additionally and this is really the biggest piece...it only allows me to upload one file even though the tables should allow many files to one tech entry?   (Maybe I need to kick some java script).

All the examples I have found either do not use model based forms, class based views or just seemingly overkill.  I just need these simple models to let me upload many files to a technical entry.   I thought I was close but fear I am not anywhere near getting this to work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** One thing I noticed is your `<form>` does not have

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Here [1](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) says:

> No characters are encoded. This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control

**2.** another thing seems missing is: `request.FILES`

```
data['file_upload'] = TechFileFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
```

Not sure if the above is how you should incorporate in your view.

The following is from doc: [about inlineformset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates) in a function-based view.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ArticleFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Another part of the doc:[about File Uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/) says:

> When Django handles a file upload, the file data ends up placed in request.FILES

Comment: Added it in, still no dice.

Comment: Thank you for this, the extra set of eyes helped.  This worked!  So now I have to just figure out how to allow me to list the files already part of the entry and to let me add arbitrary number of files...this I literally have no idea where to even start.  But at least I know the uploading is working in a formset!

Comment: Cool and thanks!  ```formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = item)``` . Here ```instance``` should be the one for listing the files already part of the entry. ```TechFileFormSet  = inlineformset_factory(Technical_Entry, Technical_Entry_Files, form=FileUploadForm, extra=1, max_num= 5) ``` You might need to check out ```extra``` and ```max_num``` for your purpose of 'add arbitrary number of files'. One thing to note is that these will give you more forms. But each form (i remember) can only take one file. because of that, I went for js library for uploading images.

Comment: That JS Library is probably the way to go, I am trying a different approach I think what is not work really is my link-formset call to jquery formset.  I am using a class based views so I am thinking my UpdateView might care about that instance=item (i mean it coudl be a list of files already uploaded for that tech entry...so still looking up what to do here.  This is the first time I have ever even attempted something like all this saddly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876644/django-class-based-createview-and-updateview-with-multiple-inline-formsets not sure if this will be helpful.

Comment: I am about to look at it, I am now trying to get the Update view and its not uploading a file but not sure what I am doing wrong there.... updated question with the complete update view.  But I will look at this stack over flow post you listed here too

Comment: the link I mentioned before seems will really help. search for ```self.object```.

Comment: I have to say that generic views are good, but seems not really friendly when what you want to do is getting complicated. With function-based view, this task should be much simpler. I look forward your solution! Once you finished, maybe you can write a complete answer for this.

Comment: I tried some updates using the self.object, the UpdateView for classes just isn't working.  Is that the only bonus to class based views is it is generic? Should I just use function based views?  I can mix and match I believe...

Comment: You definely can use class based for creating and function based for updating. Being said that, how about creating new question for updating ?

Comment: Tis done! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65101507/using-formsets-for-my-fileupload-does-not-work-when-doing-an-update-class-based